# JavaFX: GridPane, add() an integer as a label

Tags: java, javafx, int, gridpane

Forgive the horribly generic GridPane name... it'll be changed as soon as I get some input on this.

I'm adding items to a GridPane, it'll take a button, it'll take a label... it'll take pretty much anything but this int.

```
        int[] listObjA = {312,23,241};

        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

        gridpane.add(new Label("Item Listing"), 1, 1);
        gridpane.add(listObjA[0], 1, 2);
```

Of course, leaving it like that tells me "int cannot be converted to Node". Any advice? I'm mystified by how difficult it's been simply to print a variable in Java. By the way, it must be a variable because I'll have a method changing it continuously, so simply changing it to new Label("312") isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is a strongly typed language. You can't just pretend that an `int` is some kind of UI component.

Create a label for each element of the array:

```
int[] listObjA = {312,23,241};

GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

gridpane.add(new Label("Item Listing"), 0, 0);

for (int i = 0 ; i < listObjA.length; i++) {
    Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(listObjA[i]));
    gridpane.add(label, i+1, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements of the array `int[] listObjA = {312,23,241};` can't be resolved as a node type. Instead of using that , you could use it as

```
           Label firstLabel=new Label("312");
           Label secondLabel=new Label("23");
           Label thirdLabel=new Label("241");
           gridpane.add(firstLabel, x, y);
           gridpane.add(secondLabel, x,y);
           gridpane.add(thirdLabel, x, y);
```

where x , y is variable contains position wherever you want to insert Node.

Comment: You can't add the same node multiple times to a scene graph. You presumably meant to change the variable in each `add(...)` call.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the text in the labels by assigning the values in your datastructure, you need a datastructure that supports notifying other parts of your program of changes. `ObservableList` would be one such datastructure. You can use the bindings API to change bind the text in the `Label`s to your `ObservableList`'s contents:

```
ObservableList<Integer> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(Arrays.asList(312, 23, 241));

GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

gridpane.add(new Label("Item Listing"), 0, 0);

for (int i = 0, size = observableList.size(); i < size; i++) {
    Label l = new Label();
    // bind text to content at list position
    l.textProperty().bind(Bindings.valueAt(observableList, i).asString());
    gridpane.add(l, 0, i + 1);
}
```

Creating the binding here means the content of the labels automatically gets updated, if the content of the list changes. E.g.

```
Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane);

scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    private int index;

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        int i = index++ % observableList.size();
        observableList.set(i, 10 + observableList.get(i));
    }
});
```

Increments one of the values by 10 on a mouse click, which the UI shows.